# How to setup LightDM mutiseat with logind

Tags: lightdm, multiseat, systemd-logind

I have tried to setup a multiseat environment for my mediacenter (VT7: Kodi Autologin, VT8: XBMC Autologin) since Utopic. It didn't work there, so I assumed a bug. Now I retried with Vivid, still wasn't successful and found this: http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/lightdm/2014-August/000661.html

I find numerous threads asking for this, but never an answer (not even in lightdm launchpad). Is there any progress on documentation? It seems that I have to setup something with logind, but also can't find any information on that.